# Laravel GoCardless

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, oauth

I'm integrating Laravel with GoCardless to allow my users to take card payments however I'm struggling installing the GoCardless php wrapper.

I've followed the following doc:
https://developer.gocardless.com/getting-started/partners/building-an-authorisation-link/

It says to use the following, am I right in saying this will go in my controller? surely with Laravel I wouldnt need to require the vendor/autoload?

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// You should store your client ID and secret in environment variables rather than
// committing them with your code
$client = new OAuth2\Client(getenv('GOCARDLESS_CLIENT_ID'), getenv('GOCARDLESS_CLIENT_SECRET'));

$authorizeUrl = $client->getAuthenticationUrl(
  // Once you go live, this should be set to https://connect.gocardless.com. You'll also
  // need to create a live app and update your client ID and secret.
  'https://connect-sandbox.gocardless.com/oauth/authorize',
  'https://acme.enterprises/redirect',
  ['scope' => 'read_write', 'initial_view' => 'login']
);

// You'll now want to direct your user to the URL - you could redirect them or display it
// as a link on the page
header("Location: " . $authorizeUrl);
```

Apologies, if someone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate.

My controller currently looks like.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class goCardlessController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $client = new OAuth2\Client(env('GOCARDLESS_CLIENT_ID'), env('GOCARDLESS_CLIENT_SECRET'));

        $authorizeUrl = $client->getAuthenticationUrl(
          'https://connect-sandbox.gocardless.com/oauth/authorize',
          'REDIRECT_URL',
          ['scope' => 'read_write', 'initial_view' => 'login']
        );

        header("Location: " . $authorizeUrl);
    }
}
```

but I get the error:

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\OAuth2\Client' not found

Which makes sense because I haven't defined it in my controller but Im wondering how I would do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your controller:

```
use Oauth2;
```

Or alternatively, `$client = new \OAuth2\Client(....` Do note the \ before Oauth2